# Thrust - Initial device_vector

Tags: cuda, thrust

Thanks for replying my question @Eric Shiyin Kang, but not the prefix "**host**" or "**device**" cause my problem, after some try and error, I found the errors is "member data always a constant"
make a example:

```
struct OP {
    int N;
    __host__ __device__
    OP(const int n): N(n){};

    __host__ __device__
    UI operator()(const UI a) {
        int b = a * N;
        N++;
        return b;
    }
}
thrust::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), OP(2) );
```

In this case, if A is {0, 1, 2, 3, ... }, then B is {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
but the actual B should be {0, 3(1*(2+1)), 8(2*(3+1)), 15(3*(4+1)),....}

I don't know what cause this situation, cause of thrust designing? Could anyone tell me?

Comment: Don't completely change your question like this. You have just made two people waste their time by answering your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your updated Q, the host var `N` can not be updated in device code. It is generally not safe to update a shared variable many times in the parallel algorithm.

In fact the fastest way to initialize a dev vector should be using fancy iterators during the object construction stage like,

```
// v[]={0,2,4,6,8...}
thrust::device_vector<float> v(
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                thrust::counting_iterator<float>(0.0),
                _1 * 2.0),
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                thrust::counting_iterator<float>(0.0),
                _1 * 2.0) + SIZE);

// u[]={0,3,8,15...}
thrust::device_vector<float> u(
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                thrust::counting_iterator<float>(0.0),
                _1 * (_1 + 2.0)),
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                thrust::counting_iterator<float>(0.0),
                _1 * (_1 + 2.0)) + SIZE);
```

It will be a few times faster than the define-sequence-and-transform way since the latter method read/write the whole device mem `v` more than once.

Pleas note the above code only works with Thrust 1.6.0+, since the lambda expression functor is used with the fancy iterators. For Thrust 1.5.3 in CUDA 5.0, you should write a functor explicitly.

---

A for the original Q which has been deleted.

You could add both `__host__` and `__device__` qualifiers in front of the `operator()()` like,

```
struct OP {
    __host__ __device__ void operator()(int &a) {
        a *=2;
    }
}
```

and

```
struct OP {
    __host__ __device__ int operator()(int a) {
        return a*2;
    }
}
```

otherwise the compiler won't generate proper device code for GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information provided by @Eric Shiyin Kang.
I'm interesting that could fancy iterator generate a repeated sequence like {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 ....}?

Comment: @user1995868 only if you can calculate the sequence from a simple counting sequence. For example using `_1 % 3`

Comment: thanks a lot, I think I got lost in study thrust, so that I stuck in such obvious problem :(