# Accessing value of device_vector build with a functional : error I don't understand

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have a weird error that I don't understand when I initialize a device vector using a functional.

I want to create a device_vector of size 1000 with elements:
A[i] = i*0.05;

Here is my code: (seen from example here : [Thrust - Initial device_vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621401/thrust-initial-device-vector/14621493#14621493))

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>  
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(void)
{
    thrust::device_vector<float> A(
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                thrust::counting_iterator<float>(0),_1*0.05),
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                thrust::counting_iterator<float>(0),_1*0.05) + 1000);

    std::cout << "--------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A[0] is : " << A[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A[1] is : " << A[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A[100] is : " << A[100] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A[500] is : " << A[500] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine (using thrust v1.6), but when I try to access any value of my device vector (such as A[0]), I get a runtime error.

What am I doing wrong? This is probably very basic, but it's late Friday night, and somehow I can't see it!

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine for me on cuda 5.5 (with thrust v1.7)  Are you compiling with a `-arch=sm_20` or similar switch that is appropriate for your GPU?  Are you compiling with the `-G` switch (i.e. a debug project if on windows visual studio)?  Are you able to run other codes on your GPU?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I use the -G and arch switches. And yes, I can usually compile and run code on my GPU...

I just tried with thrust 1.7, but still got the same runtime error. I will try installing cuda 5.5 next (I still have 5.0). I hope that this will fix it!

Comment: Try it without the -G switch.  That can be [troublesome with thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/Debugging).

Comment: It works without the -G switch, cuda 5.5 and thrust 1.7, thanks!

Hopefully, this will also work with the rest of my code, which did not compile without -G... We'll see ;-)

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it looks like I spoke too fast the other day: indeed without the -G flag, cuda 5.5, and thrust 1.7 the code compiles and runs, however, the output is still not what I am expecting. Here is what the code returns: A[0] is -0, A[1] is -1.58819e-021, etc, etc... Far from the expected A[i] = i*0.05... Where does this come from? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thrust programs frequently will not behave correctly when compiled with the `-G` switch, so it's [recommended not to use that with thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/Debugging).

This specific behavior may vary with thrust versions, and may improve over time with newer thrust versions.  But in general, at the moment if you're having trouble with thrust code, try compiling without the `-G` switch.

Device code will frequently run faster when compiled without the `-G` switch as well, so in general `-G` should only be used when you expect to do device code debugging (e.g. with Nsight VSE or cuda-gdb), and there may also be other special cases where you want to use `-G` for test purposes, if you are focusing specifically on some aspect of device code generation.   Otherwise, you should not compile codes with `-G` as a general practice.

Comment: Do you know why Thrust is not compatible with `-G`?

Comment: No, I don't. Pretty much all I know about the issue is what is on that linked page.  I have heard anecdotally that things may/should improve with future CUDA releases, due to more testing.  The implication being that it's just bugs that need to be ironed out.  But that is just hearsay.